# CodeIgniter db function inserting incorrect single quote in query string

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

The code I am using in CodeIgniter is as follows:

```
    $where_conditions=array();
    $where_conditions['E_F_L.ei']=$ei;
    $where_conditions['E_F_L.esi <= ']=$esi;
    $where_conditions['E_F_L.si']=$si;
    $where_conditions['E_P_L.P_I']=$P_I;
    $where_conditions['E_P_M.qualify_marks <= ']="SELECT sumof3(F_T_M_P.ra , F_T_M_P.ma , F_T_M_P.mo)";
    $clearing_year=$this->db->select('E_F_L.ey,(F_T_M_P.ra + F_T_M_P.ma + F_T_M_P.mo) as mark',false)->from('E_F_L')
    ->join('E_P_L','E_P_L.efi=E_F_L.efi','inner')
    ->join('E_P_M','E_P_M.P_I=E_P_L.P_I','inner')
    ->join('F_T_M_P','F_T_M_P.epi=E_P_L.epi','inner')
    ->where($where_conditions)->order_by("F_T_M_P.tab_id", "desc")->get();
```

It generates the code as follows:

```
    SELECT E_F_L.ey, (F_T_M_P.ra + F_T_M_P.ma + F_T_M_P.mo) as mark FROM (`E_F_L`) INNER JOIN `E_P_L` ON `E_P_L`.`efi`=`E_F_L`.`efi` INNER JOIN `E_P_M` ON `E_P_M`.`P_I`=`E_P_L`.`P_I` INNER JOIN `F_T_M_P` ON `F_T_M_P`.`epi`=`E_P_L`.`epi` WHERE `E_F_L`.`ei` = '18' AND `E_F_L`.`esi` <= '113' AND `E_F_L`.`si` = '12409' AND `E_P_L`.`P_I` = '176' AND `E_P_M`.`qualify_marks` <= 'SELECT sumof3(F_T_M_P.ra , F_T_M_P.ma , F_T_M_P.mo)' ORDER BY `F_T_M_P`.`tab_id` desc
```

The required thing is:

```
    SELECT E_F_L.ey, (F_T_M_P.ra + F_T_M_P.ma + F_T_M_P.mo) as mark FROM (`E_F_L`) INNER JOIN `E_P_L` ON `E_P_L`.`efi`=`E_F_L`.`efi` INNER JOIN `E_P_M` ON `E_P_M`.`P_I`=`E_P_L`.`P_I` INNER JOIN `F_T_M_P` ON `F_T_M_P`.`epi`=`E_P_L`.`epi` WHERE `E_F_L`.`ei` = '18' AND `E_F_L`.`esi` <= '113' AND `E_F_L`.`si` = '12409' AND `E_P_L`.`P_I` = '176' AND `E_P_M`.`qualify_marks` <= (SELECT sumof3(F_T_M_P.ra , F_T_M_P.ma , F_T_M_P.mo)) ORDER BY `F_T_M_P`.`tab_id` desc
```

CI is inserting unwanted single quotes to query string in where statement near:

```
    AND `E_P_M`.`qualify_marks` <= 'SELECT sumof3(F_T_M_P.ra , F_T_M_P.ma , F_T_M_P.mo)'
```

Is their any way to prevent it? i have tried using FALSE

```
$this->db->select('E_F_L.ey,(F_T_M_P.ra + F_T_M_P.ma + F_T_M_P.mo) as mark',false)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CI, but your `WHERE` clause containing the non-standard comparison (`<=`) and the `SELECT` probably needs to be added in a different way. In normal circumstances the quoting is completely correct. Does the manual have anything here?

Comment: Try adding FALSE to your where() clause like so: `where($where_conditions, FALSE)`. According to CI docs: "If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks."

Comment: hi the problem got resolved by inserting blank space in front and end of the select statement like this    $where_conditions['E_P_M.qualify_marks <= ']=" SELECT sumof3(F_T_M_P.ra , F_T_M_P.ma , F_T_M_P.mo) ";

Comment: try this :where($where_conditions,NULL, FALSE),add second parameter with NULL value and then False parameter.